# How to fix `The array passed as the value prop to the Context provider changes every render` typescript error

Tags: typescript

I have a context and a provider as following:

```
const SearchParamsStateProvider = ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  return (
    <SearchParamsStateContext.Provider value={[searchParams, setSearchParams]}>
      {children}
    </SearchParamsStateContext.Provider>
  );
};

const SearchParamsStateContext = createContext<
  [searchParams: URLSearchParams, setSearchParams: SetURLSearchParams]
>([
  new URLSearchParams(''),
  (
    search?:
      | URLSearchParamsInit
      | ((prev: URLSearchParams) => URLSearchParamsInit),
  ) => search,
]);
```

The typescript is throwing an error on the line: `value={[searchParams, setSearchParams]}`:

> The array passed as the value prop to the Context provider (at line
> 12) changes every render. To fix this consider wrapping it in a
> useMemo hook.

So I tried using useMemo:

```
const value = useMemo(
    () => [searchParams, setSearchParams],
    [searchParams, setSearchParams],
  );

  return (
    <SearchParamsStateContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </SearchParamsStateContext.Provider>
  );
```

Which didn't work:

```
Type '(URLSearchParams | SetURLSearchParams)[]' is not assignable to type '[searchParams: URLSearchParams, setSearchParams: SetURLSearchParams]'.
  Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.
```

For some reason the type returned from useMemo is: `(URLSearchParams | SetURLSearchParams)[]` where it should be:  `[searchParams: URLSearchParams, setSearchParams: SetURLSearchParams]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array type is being generalized. Try adding `as const` after the returned array in your memo, or adding an explicit type parameter to your `useMemo` call.

```
const value = useMemo(
  () => [searchParams, setSearchParams] as const,
  [searchParams, setSearchParams],
);
```

or

```
const value = useMemo<[URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams]>(
  () => [searchParams, setSearchParams],
  [searchParams, setSearchParams],
);
```